# Rails: Remove foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have following association with user and semester. And I created user table with semester id as foreign key. So user is not created if semester id not present. But semester id is optional in the registration form.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :semester
end
class Semester < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :users do |t|
          t.string :email
          t.references :semester, foreign_key: true
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

So how can I create another migration to drop the foreign key constraint? So in the user table I there should be two columns email and semester_id but semester_id should not have foreign key constraint because it is an optional field.

Answer (score 19):

```
class RemoveSemestersFKFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    if foreign_key_exists?(:users, :semesters)
      remove_foreign_key :users, :semesters
    end
  end
end
```

Remember to set the association as `optional: true` to remove the presence validation as well.

- [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html)

Comment: You might need to do `change_column :users, :semester_id, :integer, null: true` if the column is not nullable as well.

Comment: what about rolling back this migration? it will not create foreign_key back

Comment: ... it will not create foreign_key back because of 'foreign_key_exists?' condition.. without this condition it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue when working on a Rails 6 application.

**Here's how I solved it**:

I had a `Users` table and a `Roles` table. I wanted the `Users` table to belong to the `Roles` table, that I wanted to add a reference of the `Roles` table to the `Users` table. I also had an `Admin` and `Student` Models that inherit from the `Users` table

Firstly, create a migration to add a reference of the `Roles` table to the `Users` table:

```
rails generate migration AddRoleRefToUsers role:references
```

This will create a migration file that contains the following:

```
class AddRoleRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :role, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Simply change `null: false` to `null: true`. So that we will have;

```
class AddRoleRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :role, null: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

And then migrate the database:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Finally, check your `user` model:

It will contain the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Simply add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` association. So that we will have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role, optional: true
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

Make the reference optional in your model :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :semester, optional: true
end
```

[See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference), 4.1.2.11

Comment: Not a good idea since foreign keys are not nullable in most DBs. That just removes the application level validation.

Comment: What would you advise ?

Comment: `remove_foreign_key` obviously.